# Passing Values to PHP page from a Javascript Function

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am trying to pass a value to another php page from a javascript function.

The function is as follows:

```
function selectCustomer(id) {
if(str.toUpperCase().replace(' ','')  != id.toUpperCase()){
    var stageSeletedValue = $('#'+id).children('#listValue').text();
    $('.stageDropdown').children('#stageValue').text(stageSeletedValue);
    var enquiry_id=document.getElementById('enquiry_id').value;
    var strUrl='stage-change/'+enquiry_id+'/'+stageSeletedValue;
    $.ajax({
        url : strUrl,
        success : function(data) {
//          $('#stageChange').html(data);
            if(data=='true'){
                console.log(data); 
                    //if (stageSeletedValue !=='Quote Sent') {
                    //  window.location.reload();
                    //}
                //window.location.reload();
                function popup('form.php');
            }
            },
        }); 
    }
 }
```

popup Function is as follows:

```
function popup(URL) {
 day = new Date();
 **URL=URL+"?id=+id";**
 id = day.getTime();
 eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=880,height=300');");

}
```

A pop up has to appear( with form.php?id=+id ) passing the id to the form.php page. But its not working. Can anyone pls guide me on this. I am very new to Ajax and Javascript. Thankx in advance.

Comment: You reload the page before calling your popup function ? Why ?

Comment: sorry since its ajax i dont have to reload the page. I was trying with pure php function initially. Since its ajax i dont have to relload the page to grab the id.

Comment: i edited the question. i dont have to reload the page. In the function i should be able to call a pop up function. In the pop up function i should link a form.php page passing the +id value.

Comment: Can anyone pls help me on the same.

Comment: `function popup('form.php');` with the `function` keyword in front, you appear to be defining the function there. To call a function, you don't use `function`, you simply use `popup('form.php');`. Also check your console for errors or warnings.